# Emacs stops loading at vc-git

Tags: carbon-emacs

I have a remote repository (version controlled with Git) that's mounted via ExpanDrive. I've created a macro that will load a file with Emacs as follows:
I'm using OSX 10.6.4 and GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) :

alias carbon='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs '

To load the file I just run $> carbon file_name.here &

Emacs starts up, loads a few things, and then halts. On the bottom of the Emacs window I see "loading vc-git..." and it just sticks there.

Now, the tricky bit. If I go to Finder, right-click the file I want to open and select "Open With -> Emacs" everything loads and works. The file along with it's contents are loaded and look fine.

Is there something wrong with my alias? I've let the application sit there for a couple minutes waiting for the file to load... and nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alias carbon='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app $*'